# Advanced Algorithms Problems ("Nice Triangle"): Prime number Pyramid where every number depends on numbers above it

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, dynamic-programming

I'm currently studying for an advanced algorithms and datastructures exam, and I simply can't seem to solve one of the practice-problems which is the following:

1.14) "Nice Triangle"

A "nice" triangle is defined in the following way:

1. There are three different numbers which the triangle consists of, namely the first three prime numbers (2, 3 and 5).
2. Every number depends on the two numbers below it in the following way.

   - Numbers are the same, resulting number is also the same. (2, 2 => 2)
   - Numbers are different, resulting number is the remaining number. (2, 3 => 5)

Given an integer N with length L, corresponding to the base of the triangle, determine the last element at the top

For example:
Given N = 25555 (and thus L = 5), the triangle looks like this:

```
    2
   3 5
  2 5 5
 3 5 5 5
2 5 5 5 5
```

=> 2 is the result of this example

What does the fact that every number is prime have to do with the problem?

By using a naive approach (simply calculating every single row), one obtains a time-complexity of O(L^2).
However, the professor said, it's possible with O(L), but I simply can't find any pattern!!!

Comment: Through excessive testing, it also seems to me as though swapping numbers at index i and L-i does not change the result, but I totally lack the intuition behind it and I don't know how to use this fact.

Comment: You are correct.  See the first option in my answer.  The digit at i is added to the output the same number of times as the digit at L-i

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure why this problem would be used in an advanced algorithms course, but yes, you can do this in O(l) = O(log n) time.

There are a couple ways you can do it, but they both rely on recognizing that:

1. For the problem statement, it doesn't matter what digits you use.  Lets use 0, 1, and 2 instead of 2, 3, and 5.  Then
2. If a and b are the input numbers and c is the output, then c = -(a+b) mod 3
3. You can build the whole triangle using c = a+b mod 3 instead, and then just negate every second row.

Now the two ways you can do this in O(log n) time are:

- For each digit d in the input, calculate the number of times (call it k) that it gets added into the final sum, add up all the kd mod 3, and then negate the result if you started with an even number of digits.  That takes constant time per digit.  Alternatively:
- recognize that you can do arithmetic on n-sized values in constant time.  Make a value that is a bit mask of all the digits in n.  That takes 2 bits each.  Then by using bitwise operations you can calculate each row from the previous one in constant time, for O(log n) time altogether.

Here's an implementation of the 2nd way in python:

```py
def niceTriangle(n):
    # a vector of 3-bit integers mod 3
    rowvec = 0
    # a vector of 1 for each number in the row
    onevec = 0
    # number of rows remaining
    rows = 0
    # mapping for digits 0-9
    digitmap = [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]
    # first convert n into the first row
    while n > 0:
        digit = digitmap[n % 10]
        n = n//10
        rows += 1
        onevec = (onevec << 3) + 1
        rowvec = (rowvec << 3) + digit

    if rows%2 == 0:
        # we have an even number of rows -- negate everything
        rowvec = ((rowvec&onevec)<<1) | ((rowvec>>1)&onevec)

    while rows > 1:
        # add each number to its neighbor
        rowvec += (rowvec >> 3)
        # isolate the entries >= 3, by adding 1 to each number and
        # getting the 2^2 bit
        gt3 = ((rowvec + onevec) >> 2) & onevec
        # subtract 3 from all the greater entries
        rowvec -= gt3*3
        rows -= 1
    return [2,3,5][rowvec%4]
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, using modular arithmetic to get a closed mathematical expression seems reasonable.
I guess the confusion that this problem gave me came from the fact, that we had never done something like this before and this problem was listed under introductory problems.

Comment: You mean mod 3, right?

Comment: @Dave yes, mod 3. thanks.   W.r.t how many times, think of it backwards.  The last number uses each of the two in the next row once...  the counts make Pascal's triangle.

Comment: Regarding the second approach to achieve a O(log N) solution:
What sort of bitwise operation are you refering to that can solve this problem?

Comment: @Hrvoje1999 I added an implementation of that

Comment: Damn, thank you so much. That's a beautiful implementation I would've never come up by myself!!

Comment: Given the structure of the triangle in the diagram, I think you are mistaken about it being O(log n). Except for the ends, each element on the base feeds two elements on the row above it. The width of each row only decreases by 1 making its height equal to its base. There would only be an O( log n) solution if it formed a binary tree.

Comment: Given that this problem can be solved in linear time for length L and the fact that log(N) = L, I don't see the problem here.